# How to scale nav bar on resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a simple site so far but have two issues. I have done everything with percentages because the site might go up on a high def tv and i want them to scale well. The scaling works with the images but id also like to scale the navbar background and text so that it doesnt end up looking small.

The second issue is When the site is squished the bottom image covers the nav bar and doesn't flow under the nav bar element. Id just like this feature because it would scale well for smartphones.

Here is the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headish.css">
    <title>New Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="tophead">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />    
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Biographies">Biographies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="maincont">
          <img src="images/second.png" alt="image">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
    html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;

}

#tophead {
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

#tophead img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto%;

}
#tophead ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;


}
#tophead li {
    display: inline-block;

    }
#tophead a {
  background: #2dbaf0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "arial";
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;

}
#tophead a:hover {
  background: #f8a52b;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
#tophead li:first-child a {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#tophead li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#maincont {
    padding-left: 10%;

    }
#maincont img{
    border-radius: 7%;
    width: 30%;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get an answer from your username but if you are referring to Allan Crabtree's post, it hasnt. I greatly appreciate any help but when i re-size the window (in chrome and firefox) the #maincontent img still overlaps nav bar menu. Any ideas my internet friend?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the image from flowing into other elements, use `clear:both` on your `#maincontent img`

Edit : A good article can be found on it here which suggests other methods. http://quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Edit2: This only applys to floated elements, I have just noticed you havn't used floats atall. See my comment below

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didnt quite work. The image overlaps the nav bar when the screen is minimized. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You only need the `#container` to be styled - Don't include the `html, body` as well. You also don't need the `clear:both` I mentioned in the previous answer.